# Score для указания суммарного количества голосов за сообщение

Tags: поддержка, статус-завершено, локализация, термины

Как образом лучше перевести слово "score" в предложениях указывающих суммарное количество голосов за и против за сообщение?

Например,

> added 3 posts score > 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Выбранный вариант*.

> рейтинг

Например, все сообщения с рейтингом 2 и выше.

---

*Остальные варианты*.

**Вариант 1**

У меня было так:

> 2606: There is no commenting in this phase, only one up or down vote per candidate. The candidate vote scores are all public.

перевел так:

> На данном этапе комментарии отключены. Открыто только голосование "за" или "против". Количество голосов, набранное кандидатами, видно всем.

т.е. "голоса", "количество голосов 'за'".

> added 3 posts score > 0
>   добавлено 3 сообщения, получившие голоса "за"

или

> added 3 posts score > 2
>   добавлено 3 сообщения, получившие больше 2 голосов "за".

С точки зрения голосования за и против может быть и 5-2, но так ли в конечном счете это важно? посчитать количество за и против отдельно друг от друга можно лишь по истории репутации. А видна всем всегда будет только одна цифра - общее количество голосов а сколько в них минусов было, имхо, не так важно.

**Вариант 2**

> оценка

Например, все сообщение с оценкой 2 и выше.