# Неправильный перевод в описании значка для метки

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, термины

Сейчас [описание значка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/104/python) выглядит следующим образом:

> Заработать не менее 100 баллов репутации за минимум 20 **общих ответов
>   от своего имени** на вопросы с меткой python.

В то время, как [на SO сказано](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/267/python), что значок дается за `non-community wiki answers`:

> Earn at least 100 total score for at least 20 **non-community wiki
>   answers** in the python tag.

Предлагаю перефразировать описание, потому что оно явно не согласуется с оригиналом.

Answer (score 3):

да и «баллы репутации» здесь, мне кажется, не к месту:

насколько я вижу, учитывается количество **голосов**, а не начисленные за них «баллы репутации».

к примеру: вот мои ответы с меткой [`linux`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:178576+[linux]). даже на первой странице я вижу уже 18 **голосов** (даже без учёта «принятых»), которые «принесли» 180 **баллов**. а знак — не присвоен.

**обновление 20150721**

после набора 4000 баллов в профиле на закладке «активность» отображается прогресс по меткам. там тоже перепутаны голоса (рейтинг) и «баллы репутации»:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это, скорее, вопрос к алгоритму подсчёта. А почему ваши данные противоречат тому, что начисление идёт за баллы?

Comment: А, вы имеете в виду, что у вас уже давно должен был быть бронзовый линукс?

Comment: @VladD, потому что 100 **баллов репутации** по этой метке у меня давным-давно **уже есть**. а вот ста **голосов** — пока **нет**. потому и бронзового знака пока нет.

Comment: @VladD, собственно, в оригинале речь именно о голосах, насколько я понимаю английский и принятую на [so] терминологию.

Comment: Хм. Это серьёзное изменение, давайте-ка переспросим у админов в чате.

Comment: Задал вопрос в чате, ждём-с.

Comment: Интересно. Неужели на тематический бронзовый знак надо аж 1000 баллов по теме?

Comment: @VladD, получается — да.

Comment: Хм, подсчитал свои баллы за многопоточность. Там тоже выходит, что так. Тогда надо менять _много_ строк.

Comment: @VladD, кстати, если считать **голоса**, то, по идее, **принятые** (автором вопроса) ответы не учитываются, т.е. в реальности (в пересчёте на **баллы**), выходит намного больше, чем тысяча баллов.

Comment: Там не репутация, а рейтинг, т.е. количество голосов за минус количество голосов против.

Answer (score 2):

Один из возможных вариантов - явно указать, что общие ответы не учитываются:

> Заработать не менее 100 баллов рейтинга за минимум 20 **ответов
>   (исключая общие)** на вопросы с меткой python.

Comment: Может быть, просто _за минимум 20 ответов (исключая общие)_, чтобы не повторять слово «ответ»?

Comment: Думал над этим. Мне тоже не нравится дублирование слова "ответ", но почему-то мне тот вариант не приглянулся. Быть может под вечер уже глаз замылился. Вообще, должно звучать лучше, сейчас поправлю.

Comment: Может, отдельным вариантом?

Answer (score 2):

Еще один вариант, но с инвертированными условиями:

> **Опубликовать не менее 20 ответов (исключая общие) с суммарным 
>   рейтингом не менее 100** на вопросы с меткой python.

Answer (score 1):

На основе [ответа soon](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/776/181472)

> Набрать не менее 100 очков рейтинга за не менее чем 20 ответов (исключая общие) на вопросы с меткой [python].

Почему именно «очки рейтинга»:

«Голоса рейтинга» — запутывает. Рейтинг строится на основе голосов, но не состоит из них.

«Баллы рейтинга» — тоже немного запутывает. Баллы обычно применяются в какой-то балльной системе, где есть ограниченная шкала, например от 0 до 100. Можно подумать, что требуется, чтобы в среднем каждый вопрос имел какое-то количество голосов — а это в корне неверно.

«Очки рейтинга» — это как раз то, что нужно. Очки зарабатываются в любом количестве.

Comment: *"Очки"* вместо *"голосов"* или *"баллов"* мне больше нравятся, поддерживаю.

Comment: По поводу перевода очки/баллы у нас было обсуждение на [мета.ХК](http://meta.hashcode.ru/questions/3424/). Если менять, то **везде**, а не только в этом месте. Поэтому давайте оставаться в рамках обсуждаемой проблемы.

Comment: @VladD: меня огорчают ссылки на сторонний сайт, на котором я не могу ни голосовать, ни отвечать. Тем более, там голосование идет одновременно за выбор двух терминов. Буду снова здесь поднимать тему.

Comment: @VladD: а ещё там нет никакой аргументации. Просто захотел кто-то и изменил «очки» на «баллы». Почему, зачем?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну, не "кто-то", а наш комьюнити менеджер. А голосовать там, возможно, несколько поздно, т.к. в период локализации голосовали на *той мете* и приняли эти решения.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: ... и теперь такой перевод **везде**. Если менять, то тоже везде.

Comment: @Nofate у хэшкода другой интерфейс. Я в нем не имею возможности увидеть, был это менеджер или кто-то ещё. И повторю, что нет никакой  аргументации выбора.

Comment: Да не, все так же. Смотрите в историю изменений вики-ответа,  видите, кто это был. *Expert* это Nicolas. Вообще, отписался более подробно в вашем вопросе.

Comment: @VladD: да, я отлично понимаю, что если менять используемый термин — то везде. И что это трудоемко. Я просто хочу, чтобы актуальное обсуждение этого решения хранилось на мете StackOverflow, а не на стороннем сайте. Ну и если совсем уж в идеале — то чтобы там были объяснены критерии выбора.

Answer (score 1):

Аналог [этого](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/776/176045) ответа. *"Голоса"* убраны совсем

> Набрать не менее 100 **рейтинга** за минимум 20 **ответов (исключая
>   общие)** на вопросы с меткой python.

Answer (score -1):

С учетом принятой на данный момент терминологии касаемо [перевода "score"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/487/score-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), получается следующий вариант:

> Набрать не менее 100 **голосов рейтинга** за минимум 20 **ответов
>   (исключая общие)** на вопросы с меткой python.

Предлагаю подумать насчет *"голосов рейтинга"*.

Если заменить *"голоса"* на *"баллы"*, то возникнет путаница с репутацией.
Если убрать *"голоса"* совсем, то фраза *"не менее 100 рейтинга за минимум 20 ответов"*, на мой взгляд, звучит неполно.

С другой стороны, хоть рейтинг и составляется из голосов "за" и "против", словосочетание *"голоса рейтинга"* слабо сочетается.

Comment: Может, не «голосов рейтинга», а просто «рейтинга» или «баллов рейтинга»?

Comment: Тоже думал об этом, и расписал свои рассуждения под переводом. Решил, что если акцентируют на этом внимание, то опубликую еще один вариант ответа.

Comment: акцентирую. :) Тут очень важно понимать, что не репутация, а сумма голосов. То есть не включается репутация за принятые ответы и примерно в 10 раз меньше. Но рейтинг составляется не из голосов, а на основе голосов. Поэтому «голоса рейтинга» - неверно.

Comment: Именно. Я вчера вечером это проморгал, каюсь. Сейчас добавлю еще варианты.