# Предлагаю полностью и навсегда перестать использовать ссылки на мету ХэшКода

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, правила, stackoverflow, нытьё

Достаточно часто при обсуждении каких-то вопросов на meta.ru.stackoverflow.com [используются ссылки на meta.hashcode.ru](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/751/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8/779?noredirect=1#comment2211_779). По этой ссылке находится обсуждение, в котором сообщество HashCode приняло какое-то решение, и это решение теперь должно влиять на работу и правила StackOverflow на русском.

**Что я предлагаю:**

1. Полностью исключить использование таких ссылок.
2. Все значимые вопросы перенести на meta.ru.stackoverflow.com и, возможно, возобновить обсуждение. Обязательно перенести ответы.
3. Все неперенесенные обсуждения на HashCode считать не имеющими силы для StackOverflow на русском вне зависимости от того, касаются ли они SO.RU.
4. Находить старые записи и редактировать, заменяя ссылки на Хэшкод ссылками на RU.SO. Если это значимый комментарий — дублировать с новой ссылкой.

**Аргументы:**

1. В сети StackExchange существует стандарт, по которому ответ, состоящий из ссылок на сторонние сайты, не считается качественным ответом. Ссылки через какое-то время могут стать битыми. Если закроется Мета Хэшкода — они все станут битыми. Поэтому ссылаться на Мету Хэшкода нельзя.
2. Участники StackOverflow на русском не могут принять участие в обсуждении. Нельзя дать свой вариант ответа, нельзя проголосовать, нельзя оставить комментарий. Это отстраняет пользователей от участия в управлении сайтом. Поэтому использовать эти вопросы нельзя.
3. Источником правил на сайтах сети Stack Exchange являются мета-сайты этой же сети. Нигде не сказано, что им является мета сайта HashCode.
4. Это другой сайт и другое сообщество. Не все участники HashCode перешли на StackOverflow, зато здесь есть много участников, которые не пользовались HashCode — как новых, так и приходящих с StackOverflow на английском.

> **Что я НЕ предлагаю:**

- Удалять весь Transifex
- Начинать весь перевод заново
- Менять перевод какого-то конкретного термина.

Вообще **ничего, касающегося переводов я НЕ предлагаю в этом вопросе**. Пожалуйста, не надо возражать мне по поводу переводов. Я даже удалил пример про score, потому что это просто пример, а не предмет вопроса.

---

К ответу Nofate:

> Я надеюсь, старая Мета будет вскоре закрыта, чтобы избежать недопонимания.

И тогда все ссылки на неё, данные в многочисленных комментариях и ответах [(пример)](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/a/39/177015), станут битыми. Как и происходит с ЛЮБЫМИ ссылками. Я не понимаю, почему ссылки на мету Хэшкода являются какими-то особенными и **почему можно дать ответ, состоящий только из этих ссылок**?

Comment: Вы предлагаете снести весь перевод в транзифексе и подождать когда вы лично что-то там себе придумаете и обсудите? В таком случае к бардаку призываете вы. Если вы нашли ошибку в переводе, публикуйте сообщение на мете и ждите/добивайтесь ее исправления. Ошибка с reputation vs score не оспаривается, но и монастырь не ваш личный.

Comment: @YuraIvanov я вообще о другом говорю. Перечитайте вопрос.

Comment: А вы вчитайтесь в комментарий. На старой мете обсуждался весь существующий перевод. Перевод делали несколько человек. То, что было обсуждено на Мете.ХК являлось руководством к действию. Если не учитывать то, что обсуждалось на Мете.ХК, перевода как такового не будет.

Comment: Поздно уже. Там 3 месяца назад все обсудила и порешила уже группа переводчиков, зачем они вам я не могу понять?

Comment: @igumnov: да я не хочу перевод менять! Я хочу, чтобы перестали давать ссылки на мету Хэшкода как на что-то значащее. Ну другой это сайт.

Comment: @igumnov: специально отредактировал вопрос, чтобы явно обозначить, что вопрос не касается переводов.

Comment: @YuraIvanov: нужно просто перенести все важные вопросы с Хэшкода и после этого раз и навсегда перестать на нее ссылаться.

Comment: @YuraIvanov: про снос транзифекса написал отдельно в вопросе.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я не знаю есть ли у вас доступ в транзифекс, но там тоже ссылки на обсуждения в старой мете. Ничего плохого в ней нет. Вы неправильно ставите вопрос. Старая мета - не место для обсуждения чего-то, а источник для первой ревизии перевода. Ссылаются туда не потому что лень переносить что-либо, а потому что оно уже есть и покрылось толстым слоем пыли.

Comment: Вы спросили почему конкретный термин переведен так, вам дали ссылку "откуда ноги растут", вам не предлагали участвовать в голосовании или спорить с мнениями или отсутствием мнений. Переносить со старой меты какие-либо обсуждения имело смысл в первые недели, что и было сделано. То, что сейчас происходит на ru.SO и обсуждалось на meta.ХК совершенно разные вещи. А реакция моя была в основном на слово бардак.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На данный момент мы закончили переносить публикации, которые имеют отношение к новому сообществу (например, все вопросы касающиеся перевода). В самое ближайшее время будет добавлено перенаправление с http://meta.hashcode.ru/ на http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/, а теперь на http://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/.

Answer (score 5):

С тем, что все ключевые обсуждения со старой Меты нужно перенести сюда я полностью согласен. И, насколько я знаю, @NicolasChabanovsky этим занимался. Более того, конкретно этот беспокоящий вас вопрос про "score" [был перенесен](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/457). Я надеюсь, старая Мета будет вскоре закрыта, чтобы избежать недопонимания.

А теперь, с чем я не согласен:

> Это другой сайт и другое сообщество

Нет, это то же самое сообщество, переехавшее на другой сайт. То что появляются новые участники - это прекрасно. Но нет принципиальной разницы появились ли они уже на SO или на ХК. Есть пользователи, которые присоединились в переходный период и сейчас активно участвуют в жизни сообщества уже на SO.

> Участники StackOverflow на русском не могут принять участие в обсуждении.

Я бы вообще рассмотрел возможность заморозки решений по локализации основных терминов, т.к. если периодически будет подниматься волна "давайте изменим термин Х", то ни у кого не будет ни сил ни желания причесывать локализацию. Лучше сосредоточиться на явно проблемных местах, где локализация некорректна.

> У меты HashCode, похоже, были другие стандарты обсуждения. Часто бывает непонятно, как принимались решения.

Обсуждения ни чем в корне не отличались. Просто активных участников, которых интересовала внутренняя жизнь сайта было несколько меньше, поэтому решения о переводе терминов просто принимались голосованием без долгих дискуссий: @NicolasChabanovsky публиковал варианты, кто-то мог добавить свои. Несколько дней давалось на голосование, затем принятые термины уходили в работу. Кто проголосовал - тот проголосовал. RU.SO находился в закрытой бете не очень долго, и не было времени на долгие дискуссии по каждому ключевому слову.

> Обсуждается выбор двух терминов одновременно

Так и понятия связаны между собой.

> Нет никакой аргументации предлагаемых вариантов.

См. выше.

> Не объясняется, почему выбран вариант «баллы».

Волевое решение администрации.

> Я бы отметил ответы как не-ответы, но не могу, потому что вопрос — на другом сайте.

Какой смысл, если решение было принято администрацией и ушло в работу?